# Return only rows containing a specified string in their string array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to get all of the groups of records that have a specific value (or set of values) within a string array in PostgresSQL. For example, take the following table

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| user_id |    date    | group  |
+---------+------------+--------+
|       1 | 2019-02-06 | groupA |
|       1 | 2019-02-06 | groupB |
|       1 | 2019-02-06 | groupC |
|       2 | 2019-02-06 | groupB |
|       2 | 2019-02-06 | groupC |
|       3 | 2019-02-06 | groupA |
|       3 | 2019-02-06 | groupC |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

I can group them with the following query:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   date,
   string_agg(group, ',') as groups
FROM t
GROUP BY
   user_id,
   date
```

which gives the following;

```
+---------+------------+-------------------------+
| user_id |    date    |         groups          |
+---------+------------+-------------------------+
|       1 | 2019-02-06 |  {groupA,groupB,groupC} |
|       2 | 2019-02-06 |  {groupB,groupC}        |
|       3 | 2019-02-06 |  {groupA,groupC}        |
+---------+------------+-------------------------+
```

But I only want groups that contain `groupA`. That is, here is the desired output:

```
+---------+------------+-------------------------+
| user_id |    date    |         groups          |
+---------+------------+-------------------------+
|       1 | 2019-02-06 |  {groupA,groupB,groupC} |
|       3 | 2019-02-06 |  {groupA,groupC}        |
+---------+------------+-------------------------+
```

How do I filter out rows that don't contain `groupA`?

Here's one query I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   date,
   string_agg(group, ',') as groups
FROM t
GROUP BY
   user_id,
   date
HAVING 'groupA' IN string_agg(group, ',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN`can't be used with lists of elements, `string_agg()` returns a single character value.

But you can aggregate the values into an array that can be used in the having clause:

```
SELECT user_id,
       "date",
       string_agg("group", ',') as groups
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id, "date"
HAVING 'groupA' = any (array_agg("group"));
```

Another option is to use the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) `@>`

```
SELECT user_id,
       "date",
       string_agg("group", ',') as groups
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id, date
HAVING array_agg("group") @> array['groupA']::varchar[]
```

Comment: Thanks! The first method works for me, but the second method returns the following error: "ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts." I tried tacking on a ::varchar at the end to cast, but that didn't work.

Comment: I assumed `"group"` (which is a horrible name) was defined as `text`. But you can cast the array to a `varchar[]` (see my edit) or use `array['groupA'::varchar]`